# Windows 10 Choose album for slideshow

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

Windows 10 keeps reverting from my selected background folder to its default folder for desktop backgrounds.

I do have 3 PCs sharing themes. However they are all pointing to their *local* Dropbox directory where the folder with background images resides.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have Sync (themes) enabled per chance, and using multiple devices?

Comment: I do. Let me add more to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been a bug.  After installing the Windows 10 Anniversary Edition, it no longer reverts back to the default setting.